# flexbox adding 1px left margin in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I'm having trouble with Safari adding a 1px margin/gap to the left on the first element in a flexbox row. I've attached an image below of the issue:

[image]

The flex box css is:

```
.equal-height {
        display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
        display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
        display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
        display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
        display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

The child elements are set to the following:

```
.child-div {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 33.3333%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But they I have noticed that they are computed with no float

Comment: Please add any code you are using at the moment

Comment: I've just added some css thanks Shaun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

file: style.css;
line: 1028

```
.row:before, .row:after{
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
```

add:

```
width: 100%
```

and now the "margin" is solved.

The grid system you used has problems with safari: change it.

Hope I've helped you.

Comment: Thanks a ton for that! Would've never been able to have tracked that down. And I've made some further fixes for Safari now thanks

Answer (score 6):

I've noticed this as well.  Here's what worked for me:

```
.row:before, .row:after {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was helped me.

Comment: Thanks this helped me.

Answer (score 3):

The reason they are computed with no float is that `flex` cancels them.
As per [flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/):

> float and clear have no effect on a flex item, and do not take it
>   out-of-flow. However, the float property can still affect box
>   generation by influencing the display property’s computed value.

So 100% width on the flex container as per Michael is ok, but if you want flexbox, what you want is:

```
.child-div {
        width: 33.3333%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -moz-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
        -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

i.e. You need to use either floats or flex, but not both.

You may want to have a look at this [flexbox generator](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=row&flex-wrap=wrap&justify-content=flex-end&align-items=flex-start&align-content=flex-start&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=1&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=auto&align-self%5B%5D=auto) to understand how flex works.